# Can this query be optimized? (Choosing a random row to insert, that excludes previously inserted Rows)

Tags: postgresql

I am using this query to randomly select a row in the **user** table that has not already been inserted into the **task_pool** table, laterally done per id in **task_dispersal** table.

---

PostgreSQL 16.2

```
INSERT into task_pool(user_id, order_id)
select u.user_id, task_dispersal.id
from task_dispersal
cross join lateral (
    select user_id
    from users
    tablesample bernoulli(.1)
    repeatable(random())
    where user_id not in (
        select user_id
        from task_pool
        where order_id = task_dispersal.id
    )
          order by random()
    limit 1) u
```

---

### Is there anything that can be done to optimize this query?

*I added an "explain analyze verbose" Query Plan result at end of this post*

```
create table users(
    user_id serial primary key,
    irellevant_columns varchar
    );
create table task_pool(
    id serial primary key,
    irellevant_columns varchar
    );
create table task_pool(
    task_id serial primary key,   
    order_id integer,
    user_id integer
    );
```

| user_id(serial key) | irellevant_columns |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ~~~ |
| ... | ... |
| 49156 | ~~~ |

**task_dispersal**

| id(serial key) | irellevant_columns |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ~~~ |
| 2 | ~~~ |
| ... | ... |
| 100 | ~~~ |

**task_pool**

| task_id(serial key) | order_id(not unique) | user_id (not unique) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 267 |
| 2 | 55 | 9,999 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 1 | 23 | 602 |
| 985187 | 5 | 15 |

For example, let's say there's 100 rows in task_dispersal (therefore 100 order_ids). For each of those 100 order_ids, the query will chose a random user_id in the user_table, filtering out user_id's that have already been inserted into the task_pool for that order_id.

The query above works great, but slows down as the amount of rows in users and task_pool increase (expected of course, I'd just hope to minimize the delay).

Let's say I have 985187 rows in task_pool (so 985187 task_ids), 49156 rows in user table (49156 user_ids), and 100 rows in task_dispersal (100 order_ids).

The query now takes ~9.5 seconds to complete.

---

Here is the info with explain analyze verbose:

```
"Insert on public.task_pool  (cost=21150.09..2115016.50 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=9565.389..9565.390 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=21150.09..2115016.50 rows=100 width=28) (actual time=81.912..9562.038 rows=100 loops=1)"
"        Output: nextval('pool_task_id_seq'::regclass), task_dispersal.id, users.user_id, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, NULL::integer, 0"
"        ->  Seq Scan on public.task_dispersal  (cost=0.00..4.00 rows=100 width=4) (actual time=0.019..0.147 rows=100 loops=1)"
"              Output: task_dispersal.id"
"        ->  Limit  (cost=21150.09..21150.10 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=95.599..95.599 rows=1 loops=100)"
"              Output: users.user_id, (random())"
"              ->  Sort  (cost=21150.09..21150.15 rows=24 width=12) (actual time=95.593..95.593 rows=1 loops=100)"
"                    Output: users.user_id, (random())"
"                    Sort Key: (random())"
"                    Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB"
"                    ->  Sample Scan on public.users  (cost=19563.30..21149.97 rows=24 width=12) (actual time=93.586..95.572 rows=47 loops=100)"
"                          Output: users.user_id, random()"
"                          Sampling: bernoulli ('0.1'::real) REPEATABLE (random())"
"                          Filter: (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1))"
"                          Rows Removed by Filter: 0"
"                          SubPlan 1"
"                            ->  Seq Scan on public.task_pool task_pool_1  (cost=0.00..19560.84 rows=985 width=4) (actual time=9.673..93.218 rows=995 loops=100)"
"                                  Output: task_pool_1.user_id"
"                                  Filter: (task_pool_1.order_id = task_dispersal.id)"
"                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 984192"
"Planning Time: 0.487 ms"
"Execution Time: 9565.444 ms"
```

---

I don't assume this can really be optimized, but I'm still pretty new to SQL so I thought I'd ask here.

Comment: Next time share the complete DDL for all tables and indexes involved. We can now only guess as ask about it. So, did you create an index on table `task_pool` on column `user_id` ?

Comment: Sorry! No, I didn't add any indexes, except the key indexes of course.
I assumed it would lower performance of this query because it would have to make indexes for each task inserted. I can try it with an index on user_id, and order_id

Comment: Advice: Never assume anything, just measure.

Comment: Ok, I added an index to user_id column and it increased the query time to 10.5 seconds.
I just did basic "CREATE INDEX user_ids ON task_pool (user_id)"

Comment: An index `on task_pool (order_id)` should slow down the insert slightly but speed up the select dramatically.

Comment: Yes, I actually JUST tried it on order_id and it did indeed increase the speed from 9.5 seconds to 225 ms! WOW!!!!
At this point it would be unessesary optimization, but can you guys think of anything else that may further reduce the query time?
THANK YOU BOTH!

Comment: For further improvements, we need the new query plan and the complete DDL as it is right now. Please use `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for your SQL statement, to get all the details about the query plan. All in plain text.